# Question on Botium-core along with other automation framework

Tags: botium-box

Has anyone tried using botium-core alone for web/mobile conversational testing while rest of the web page related testing remain in existing automation framework like nemo, nightwatch or roboautomation framework.

For instance login to webpage and navigating/launching chatbot can remain in existing automation framework, once launched all conversation assertion can be done through botium.

Any code or documentation references will be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Not saying the base question is bad. Excellent content. Try to rephrase to ask a more specific question. And PLEASE do not let this discourage you. This is more the place where you ask once youve been using that workflow, but are getting caught up by some specific implementation detail. If you are thinking about trying it out and want some feedback, or helpful sources, try Reddit. there is a sub (r/softwaretesting) built just for this type of question. Either way, Come back here with your more specific, in-practice, implementation types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Botium is based on [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/) / Selenium - see [Github Repository for the Botium Webdriver Connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio). For each test case it launches a separate new Selenium session or Headless chrome session, depending on the settings.

For doing what you are trying to do there is something like a Selenium session handover required, which is not supported (and I don't know if this is technically possible with WebdriverIO / Selenium).

You can (and in most cases, you have to) add your own Javascript/Selenium scripts to do the login and initial login to the chatbot widget - see [Botium in a nutshell](https://floriantreml.medium.com/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-6-e2e-testing-with-botium-box-9bd8acdf5a70). This will look like this example in *botium.json*:

```
 ...
 "WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT": "module.exports = container.findElement('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler').then(ccBtn => ccBtn.waitForClickable({ timeout: 20000 }).then(() => ccBtn.click())).then(() => container.findElement('.troy__start-icon')).then(startChat => startChat.waitForClickable({ timeout: 20000 }).then(() => startChat.click()))",
...
```

(Copied from [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio/blob/master/samples/custom/botium.json))